# How to use the ApexCharts dynamic line example in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am trying to use the ApexChart dynamic line example in a react project but am getting compilations error. I did the same for the static line example and it worked well with no problem.

The example is here https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/line-charts/realtime/

My project directory here
https://github.com/zapta/react_test/tree/main/dynamic_line

And my component class file, with the code I copied from the example, is here
https://github.com/zapta/react_test/blob/main/dynamic_line/src/MyComponent.js

During build I am getting these errors

```
ERROR in [eslint]
src\MyComponent.js
  Line 10:15:  'data' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 46:18:  'XAXISRANGE' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 63:7:   'getNewSeries' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 63:20:  'lastDate' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 67:7:   'ApexCharts' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 68:15:  'data' is not defined          no-undef
```

Most likely I need to import more stuff, but am not sure what. Any suggestions or a complete ApexCharts dynamic line React example I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line below eliminated the error messages. Will appreciate if anybody can confirm that this is the right thing to do.

```
import ApexCharts, { lastDate, data, XAXISRANGE, getNewSeries } from "apexcharts";
```